# Java based lotus agent how to change content type

Tags: java, xml, lotus-domino, lotus

I have a java agent in lotus notes in which i receive an xml and parse this.
this is the code:

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import java.io.File;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {
    private static PrintWriter pw;
    public void NotesMain() {


        try {
             Session session = getSession();
             AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();
             Database db = agentContext.getCurrentDatabase();

             //domino 03
             boolean ProductieDatabase = false;

             String ApplicatieServer = "CN=Server01";
             String OrderDB = "General\\Order.nsf";
             String TestOrderDB = "General\\TestOrder.nsf";

             String Relations= "General\\Relations.nsf";
             String Tabel= "General\\Tabel.nsf";

             org.w3c.dom.Document domdoc = null;

             lotus.domino.Document doc = agentContext.getDocumentContext();
             Item requestContent = null;
             StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
             pw = getAgentOutput();

             //Open databases

             Database RelationDB= session.getDatabase(ApplicatieServer,Relations, false);

             Database TabelDB= session.getDatabase(ApplicatieServer,Tabel, false);

             //Open order database
              Database TabelDB;
              if(ProductieDatabase == true)
              {
                TabelDB= session.getDatabase(ApplicatieServer,OrderDB, false);
              }
              else
              {
                TabelDB= session.getDatabase(ApplicatieServer,TestOrderDB, false);
              }

              //Maak nieuw request document aan
              lotus.domino.Document RequestDoc = db.createDocument();
              //Alle velden uit de http post toevoegen aan document
              Vector items = doc.getItems();
              for (int j=0; j<items.size(); j++)
                {
                 // System.out.println ("Testorders 3");
                  Item item = (Item)items.elementAt(j);
                  String fldName = item.getName();
                  String fldValue = item.getValueString();
                  RequestDoc.replaceItemValue(fldName, fldValue);
                  if ( fldName.matches("(?i).*request_content.*") )
                    {
                      sb.append( fldValue );

                    }
                }  

              RequestDoc.replaceItemValue("Form", "Response");
              RequestDoc.replaceItemValue("Status", "0");
              RequestDoc.replaceItemValue("ID_Request",  RequestDoc.getUniversalID());

              Date currentDate=new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
              SimpleDateFormat formatterDatum=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
              SimpleDateFormat formatterTijd=new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss");

              String HubwooBestandspad = "C:\\OCI\\asd\\";
              String Bestnaam = cxvxcv+ "asdasd" + RequestDoc.getUniversalID() + "_" + formatterDatum.format(currentDate) + "_" + formatterTijd.format(currentDate) + ".xml";


              Stream outStream = session.createStream();
              if (outStream.open(Bestnaam, "ASCII")) {
                if (outStream.getBytes() == 0) {
                  outStream.writeText(sb.toString());
                  outStream.close();

                }
                else
                  System.out.println("Output file exists and has content");
              }
              else{
                System.out.println("Output file open failed");
              }


                File input = new File(Bestnaam);
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                domdoc = dBuilder.parse(input);


                domdoc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

                NodeList nList = domdoc.getElementsByTagName("ItemOut");
                String test = "TEST OCI AGENT";

                for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

                    Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                    System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nList.getLength());
                    test = test + "**Delivery Date**" +  eElement.getAttribute("requestedDeliveryDate") + "!END! [" + temp + "]";
                    test = test + " " +  eElement.getElementsByTagName("SupplierPartID").item(0).getTextContent();
                    test = test + " " +  eElement.getElementsByTagName("Description").item(0).getTextContent();


                }
                RequestDoc.replaceItemValue("JSON", sb.toString());
                RequestDoc.replaceItemValue("JSON", test);
                // OM HELE XML FILE TE KRIJGEN 
                RequestDoc.replaceItemValue("XmlTU",sb.toString());
              RequestDoc.save();


              //verander content-type
              pw.println("Content-Type: text/xml");
              //verander charset
              pw.println("charset: UFT-8");
              //stuur 200 OK terug
              pw.println("200 OK");





        }
    catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

How can i change sucessfully the content type to text/xml and the charset to utf-8. I was thinking about creating an extra class which extends the HttpServlet and which has the doPost method. But how can i then implement that object in to this agent?
Now this service works, with firefox poster i also receive response 200 OK and also content-type= text/xml.. But if this service is getting called from a .net envorinment then the .net shows a protocol violation error.

Can someone help?

- code of the .net application:

  ```
   Public Function SubmitOrder(ByVal OrderXML, ByVal URL)
    Dim objXMLHTTP  'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP
    'We provide our own error handling
    On Error Resume Next

    'The MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP object allows xml to be posted to
    'external webpages.
    Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      SubmitOrder = "ERROR: Failed to create ServerXMLHTTP - " & Err.Description
      Exit Function
    End If   

    'Specify the webpage we wish to use
    objXMLHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      SubmitOrder = "ERROR: Failed to open URL - " & Err.Description
      Exit Function
    End If

    'The type of information we are sending
    objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      SubmitOrder = "ERROR: Failed to setRequestHeader - " & Err.Description
      Exit Function
    End If

    'Send the information
              objXMLHTTP.send replace(OrderXML,"UTF-16","UTF-8")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
       SubmitOrder = "ERROR: Failed to send data to " & URL & " - " & Err.Description & ", Error number --> " & Err.Number
      Exit Function
     End If


  'Return the result
    SubmitOrder = objXMLHTTP.responseText
  end Function

  public Function CheckSuccess(ByVal Response)

    'Check for any internal errors
    If Left(Response, 6) = "ERROR:" Then
      CheckSuccess = False
      Exit Function
    End If

    'If the response includes the text code="200" then the
    'export was a success
    CheckSuccess = instr(Response, "code=""200""") <> 0
  End Function
  ```

Comment: Sounds to me like you have a problem in the code on the .Net side. Can you show that code?

Comment: @RichardSchwartz see updated question

Comment: Where does OrderXML come from, and what does your replace() function do?

Comment: OrderXML is a cXML which comes from the system and it changes its charset from utf16 to utf8

Comment: Does it actually change the charset of the data? Or does it just replace the text "UTF-16" with "UTF-8"?

Comment: only changes the text

Comment: You can't simply replace the word "UTF-16" with "UTF-8" and expect it to come out okay.  If the data is UTF-16 and you want to send the data as UTF-8, you're going to have to find a way to convert it to UTF-8.